# MS-Access 2013; Change combobox options based on record data in multi-record form

Tags: ms-access

I have a form with multiple records, one per row, being pulled from a table.  I have 2 ComboBox controls on each row.  The first ComboBox's options are linked to a table of Categories.  The second ComboBox's options need to be linked to the subcategories of the first ComboBox.

I have tried having the WHERE statement in the row source at design time, which produced all the subcategories.

I have tried having the WHERE statement, and a requery command, on the change event of the category ComboBox, which produced the subcategories for the last changed category.  This was an issues because all the rows would have the same options, instead of the options being based on the category for that record/row.

What I need is for each row to query the subcategory/category mapping table and filter the results based on that row's category selection.  Is this possible?  If so, how can this be done?  I am not afraid of using VBA to get the results I need.

Answer (score 0):

In the On_Current event of the form, you can change the row source of the second combo box dynamically dependant on the value of the column of the first combo box.  You probably also need to do it on the after_update event of the first combo box to.

Something like this

```
    Select Case Me.cboCategory
Case "Category 1"
    Me.cboSubCategory.RowSource = "qryCat1Subclass"
Case "Category 2"
    Me.cboSubCategory.RowSource = "qryCat2Subclass"
Case Else
    Me.cboSubCategory.RowSource = ""
End Select
```

I don't have two combo boxes, just one, but its contents have to be based on a value in another field.  This is how I do it.

Comment: This works for dynamic filtering, but the rows with a different category will have no text in the combobox until a row with the same category is selected.

Comment: @DevLocus.  Is your Category and Subcategory  bound fields?  If they are it should work.  If it isn't then Continuous Forms only display the value in the current record on all rows. (Makes it a real pain if you want to do more fancy stuff).  I do exactly what I have said, (although I didn't refer to a combo box as the field I have labelled Me.cboCategory, in my case its a text field from the database)

Comment: And of course the Case Else is just a get out clause.  You should add more Case "Category n" elements for all possible values.

Comment: One more thought.  The cboSubCategory fields should allow values not in the ComboBox list (just to handle the case you just mentioned).

Comment: Unfortunately, to make that work I would need to display the subcategory's ID number in the combobox instead of the name because the bound column must be visible for "Limit to List" property to be "No".